# Scroll event is triggered after Task Delay

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, scroll, async-await

I'm trying to avoid multiple calls to consume rest service on `ListView` scroll but it doesn't seem to work..

#### The problem

When scrolling the `ListView`, scroll event is triggered continuously, and the rest service is called multiple times.

#### Approach

I have decided to call the service in a separate thread with 11 seconds of delay

#### Expectation

After the service is called, the `busy` property is still set to true for 11 seconds so even if the scroll event is triggered it will not call the service because the `busy` property is true.

#### Result

The service is called once but after 11 seconds the scroll event is triggered again and calls the service again.

#### Edit

I start scrolling, and event is hit multiple times because the event is triggered for every change in  scroll-Y value causing to call the service 5 times ( what I want is to call the service 1 time)

for example:

Note that the  initial scroll y value is 0. I make a swipe to scroll it.
let's say that after the swipe the scroll value is 5 (Event is hit 5 times) there fore my attempt to solve the problem is call the service in a separate thread by using Tasks, but what happens is the event is triggered and runs the task to call the service and because it runs on a different thread it's immediately done with the event ( I mean I get out of the event) and after 11 seconds the event is hit again and so on..

so what happens

what I want is to call the rest service 1 time, not 5 times.

```
private void Scrollview_Scrolled(object sender, ScrolledEventArgs e)
    {
        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
                if (IsBusy)
                    return;

                 IsBusy = true;
                 await _services.IDealsMService.GetMoreDealsAsync(param1, param2);
                 await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(11));
         }
     }
```

Comment: @Cfun nope, it does not, and I'm do not need it as I'm not awaiting the Task..

Comment: So you want to throttle or debounce the event? so it fires maximum once every 11 seconds ?

Comment: trying to do throttling

Comment: tried something similar like this and didn't work, I will still try your solution in a moment and let you know

Comment: well I've shared only part of the code, so the problem was I was also programatically scrolling from the seperate thread and that was messing things..

Comment: ah I see, good it is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
bool IsBusy { get; set; } = false;

private async void Scrollview_Scrolled(object sender, ScrolledEventArgs e)
{
    if (IsBusy)
        return;

    IsBusy = true;
    await _services.IDealsMService.GetMoreDealsAsync(param1, param2);
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(11));     
    IsBusy = false;
}
```